# Shared element Transition between Fragment and ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, transition

I have a fragment with RecylerView. When user click on Recylerview item then another fragment open with viewpager. Now i want shared tranistion between Recyler Fragment to Viewpager Fragment. How i can achieve that transition

Thanks